# Restart a new instance of a job that is not restartable

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have defined a Spring-Batch Job with Parameter restart="false", because I do not want the same instance of the Job to be started again.

```
<batch:job id="myJob" restartable="false">
    <batch:step id="myStep">
        <batch:tasklet>
            ...
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

The Job is referenced in two other more highlevel jobs:

```
<batch:job id="hightLevelJob1" restartable="false">
    <batch:step id="myHighLevelJob1Step1" next="...">
        <batch:job ref="myJob"/>
    </batch:step>
    ...
</batch:job>

<batch:job id="hightLevelJob2" restartable="false">
    <batch:step id="myHighLevelJob2Step1" next="...">
        <batch:job ref="myJob"/>
    </batch:step>
    ...
</batch:job>
```

I now have two JUnit-Tests that each starts one of the high level jobs:

```
@Autowired
private JobOperator jobOperator;

@Test
public void testHighLevelJob1() throws JobExecutionException {
    final Long executionId = jobOperator.startNextInstance("myHighLevelJob1");
    ...
}

@Test
public void testHighLevelJob2() throws JobExecutionException {
    final Long executionId = jobOperator.startNextInstance("myHighLevelJob2");
    ...
}
```

The first test runs fine, while the second one throws a JobRestartException:

```
JobInstance already exists and is not restartable
```

I am using jobOperator.startNextInstance() so it creates a **new** job. However, it seems this only applies for the high level job that is started. It looks like Spring-Batch tries to re-use the referenced job.

How can I configure the jobs to also have a new instance of the referenced job created everytime?

Answer (score 1):

You need a [JobParametersIncrementer](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/JobParametersIncrementer.html) for this to work, as the javadocs for startNextInstance clearly states: "Launch the next in a sequence of JobInstance determined by the JobParametersIncrementer attached to the specified job"

The JobParametersIncrementer helps you to increase and put a new parameter to the JobParameters and by this way a new instance of a Job can be started.

Modify your job definition bean and add an incrementer

```
<batch:job id="myJob" restartable="false" incrementer="incrementer">
    <batch:step id="myStep">
        <batch:tasklet>
            ...
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

And implement the JobParametersIncrementer class with a trivial incrementer

```
<bean id="incrementer"
        class="com...TrivialJobParametersIncrementer" />
```

You may find a sample [TrivialJobParametersIncrementer](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/templates/batch-admin-web/trunk/template/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/admin/sample/TrivialJobParametersIncrementer.java) in spring batch admin samples.

Comment: I tried this, but the exception remains the same. I was already using the class __org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementor__. When checking with debugger, the incrementor is only executed for the higher level jobs, but somehow never for the referenced job.